# Line graph plotting several levels of indicator over time in x-axis

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a data set of 600 respondents. For each respondent I want to track the level of an indicator over time using a line graph. The indicator is divided in 5 levels - 0,1,2,3,4, and I have the indicator for 4 years - 2014, 2015, 2016 and 2017.
So I want the sample number on y-axis, and one line representing each respondent across the 4 time periods indicating the level of indicator. How can this be possible? I appreciate your help!
I want to further facet out this graph using deciles of income in the income variable.

Sample dataframe:

```
df <- data.frame(c(1:5), c(0, 1, 0, 2, 2), c(1, 2, 2, 4, 4), c(2, 3, 3, 4, 4), c(3,3,3,4,4), c(10000, 200000, 15000, 40000, 350000) 
colnames(df) <- c("sample_no", paste("indicator_level_", 14:17, sep=""), "annual_income")
```

Comment: I don't understand what you want on tour x axis... Are your sure you want the sample number on y axis?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Would this be acceptable to you?

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(magrittr)
```

I only use 3 different clusters (instead of 10) based on quantile because of the number of rows.

```
df2 <- df %>%
  mutate(quantile = ntile(annual_income, 3)) %>%
  gather(indicator_level_14, indicator_level_15, indicator_level_16, indicator_level_17, 
         key = "Indicator", value = "Value")


ggplot(df2, aes(x = Indicator, y = Value, color = as.factor(sample_no))) + 
  geom_line(aes(group = sample_no)) +
  facet_wrap(~quantile) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 50, hjust = 1)) +
  labs(color = "Sample")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much for introducing me to gather and tidyr. My dataset is really wide and this is helpful. Your solution works great except on running it I realized since many respondents have similar trend, they are getting super imposed, there are 600 respondents, and so colors are also merged. and hence, one cannot tell if several respondents have the same trend of its just one. Is there a way that by the thickness of all super imposed trends one could visually guess how many respondents have same trend across time indicators.

Comment: Maybe, before gathering, you can create a new variable (say diff) which represents the difference between indicators at year 14 and year 15. And then `aes(color/linetype = diff)`. It's one way to see a general trend.